# Here Strings: What is going on here?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, heredoc, process-substitution

I'm relatively new to shell scripting, but not to programming, though I'll admit to being out of the game for a while.

In trying to get the bottom of a bug in a Bash script, I've come up with three short examples of my use of process substitution and "here strings" feeding STDIN for `while` loops, in order to avoid subshell issues.

I'm null-separating the `find` output to avoid potential struggles with unusual filename characters.

This example **works great**, and outputs the names of all folders in root:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' y; do echo "${y}"
done < <(find / -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf "%P\0" | sort -z)
```

This example **works great**, too:

```
#!/bin/bash
find / -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf "%P\0" | sort -z | \
{ while IFS= read -r -d '' y; do echo "${y}"; done }
```

But this case, where I store the `find` output in string `x` and attempt to use it as the source of my "here string", **outputs nothing**:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(find / -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf "%P\0" | sort -z)
while IFS= read -r -d '' y; do echo "${y}"; done <<< "${x}"
```

What subtlety (or denseness on my part) am I missing here?

I'm using GNU bash 4.1.7(2)-release.

Comment: Use more quotes ! `x="$(...)"`

Comment: @sputnick not necessary on variable assignments like that.

Comment: @sputnick, I tried your suggestion, but see no difference.

Comment: It's possible that bash doesn't like `\0` inside of variables.

Comment: @Kevin, it's a good practice, even if not strictly needed there.

Comment: @sputnick It is good practice to learn the language instead of typing useless code.

Comment: @sputnick, thanks for that. As I hope you'll see by my "${variable}" references, I am endeavoring to adhere to good practices.

Comment: To avoid the subshell you can use `while...done < <(find ... sort -z)`.

Comment: @Kevin, that's precisely what my first example does. And you are right--works great. Though I don't like the readability much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in bash are like C-strings and are **null-terminated**.  This should explain why it doesn't work when you try to assign the output to a variable.

As an experiment, you could try

```
a=$'foo\0bar'
echo "$a"
```

Comment: Oh. Well, that makes plenty of sense! Thanks. Though shouldn't my third example output just the first folder name, instead of nothing?

Comment: Then try the experiment in zsh.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, if the stripped-down Slackware environment I'm using for this project had zsh installed, I'd try it. Does zsh allow nulls in string variables?

Comment: @briguy328 Yes, it does. And a great many other conveniences, I highly recommend learning it.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a string to a parameter, the end of the string is terminated by the first null character. The shell can, however, pass null-character-containing strings via standard input, which can read an arbitrary byte stream.

Comment: devnull beat you to it, but thanks very much. If my code had output just one folder name, instead of zero folder names, I think that might've occurred to me. In fact, I still don't understand why it doesn't do that.